# Understanding rails migration statement (:null => false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am trying to understand the following statement, it is from a rails migration file:

```
x.datetime "new",     :null => false
x.datetime "update",  :null => false
```

I understand the the first part of both statements (everything before the comma) but I am unsure on the null portion

```
:null => false
```

Is this basically saying "if it does not exist, then it is false?"  The logic just seems a bit strange, any clarification on this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: It's just a hash argument.

Comment: @DaveNewton: If the OP can't read the quoted statements, he's fairly unlikely to understand that comment, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Well, `=> false` would define a [bound](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) `function () { return false; }`. But, `:null` is a syntax error. If it was `null:` instead, then it would be a [key for an `Object`](http://coffeescript.org/#objects_and_arrays).

Comment: Are you sure that's CoffeeScript? Looks more like something from a Rails migration to me. That sort of thing would create a couple new timestamp columns that don't allow NULLs.

Comment: are you sure this is coffeescript? This looks very much as a ruby where the last paramter is a hash

Comment: @muistooshort you are right this is from a rails migration, I am trying to work with them in coffee script.

Comment: You're trying to ... what ?! Doesn't make any sense to create rails migrations in Coffeescript

Comment: I am using the variables "new" & "update" in coffeescript (for a controller I am writing), the text from above is from a rails migration.  I am not sure what the :null => false means exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: I had taken the question to be about syntax and translation since it [originally mentioned CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15368608/1). For purpose, refer to [Peter Bloom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598317).

---

> I am not sure what the `:null => false` means exactly.

The `=>` operator is a key/value separator in Ruby, defining a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) with a `:null` key set to `false`. It's similar to `:` for an `Object` literal in CoffeeScript/JavaScript -- `{ null: false }`.

When used in an argument list, it's one option for allowing/imitating named arguments in Ruby.

The other main difference is that CoffeeScript/JavaScript use `String`s for keys while Ruby typically uses [Symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) -- `"null"` (cs/js) vs. `:null` (rb).

So, the syntactic equivalent in CoffeeScript would be:

```
x.datetime "new",     null: false
x.datetime "update",  null: false
```

In JavaScript, that's:

```
x.datetime("new",    { null: false });
x.datetime("update", { null: false });
```

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598317/2909897) below this answered my question in the right context.

Answer (score 31):

`:null => false` in a Rails migration tells your database not to accept NULL values. It can be used with `:default => 0` to tell your database to use '0' as the default value (a) when NULL or nothing is specified in a query or (b) when creating or updating an object. (Remember, '0' and NULL are not the same things.)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, rather than use `x` I'd use the standard `t` variable that is used in migrations.

Now, inside migration files the `t` object in `create_table` is actually of type [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html).

And,

```
t.datetime "new",    :null => false
t.datetime "update", :null => false
```

actually translates to

```
t.column("new", :datetime, { :null => false })
t.column("update", :datetime, { :null => false })
```

where the last argument is the options argument of the [`column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) method.

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) one of these options is `:null` which allows or disallows NULL values in the column.

So, in summary `:null => false` would mean "Do not allow NULL values in the new or update column".