# Migrations in Rails, difference between null and optional options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-migrations

Im working on learning Rails, and have found that the details are where you can really end up sinking yourself in the future. As I'm creating a very simple store, doing migrations I have a few belongs_to's that are optional object relationships. As I was reading trying to better understand null here:

[Understanding rails migration statement (:null => false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368608/understanding-rails-migration-statement-null-false/16598317)

It occurred to me that using null: true would allow that column to be null, and I was couldn't find any information / questions addressing the difference between:

```
create_table :items do |t|
  
  ...
  t.belongs_to :shopping_cart, null: true
  ...

end
```

and

```
create_table :items do |t|
  
  ...
  t.belongs_to :shopping_cart, optional: true
  ...

end
```

What should I be doing for this kind of optional relationship, I'm new to Ruby/Rails but "convention over configuration" has me wanting to understand the right way to do this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps I've just never encountered `optional` in a migration like that, but where did you find a guide suggesting using `optional`?

Comment: here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589399/add-nullable-foreign-key-in-rails/37803756 (disclaimer, i may simply just be misreading the linked stack post)

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be confused about how `optional` works in a `belongs_to` relationship.

In a migration file, you're telling the database how a table is going to be structured. What columns are called, what kind of data they hold, whether or not `NULL` is an acceptable value, etc. This relates directly to your model code through the ActiveRecord ORM that Rails uses.

So in a migration, `null: true` means at the database level that `NULL` is an acceptable value for the given column. `null: false` would mean that `NULL` is not acceptable and that you always expect something to be stored there. Generally, `null: false` is used in conjunction with a default so that there's always a value in the column even if it's not specified when the record is created.

`optional` is used in the model code itself to tell ActiveRecord that a `belongs_to` relationship is expected, but it may not exist and that's ok. In your case, that would look something like this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shopping_cart, optional: true
end
```

That means that an item may have a `shopping_cart_id` present in the database, but it doesn't have to. Items can exist with a `shopping_cart_id` column that contains `NULL`.

Really `null: true` and `optional` aren't directly related. Nullability at the database level is determined by what's in a migration file. The presence of a foreign_key in a `belongs_to` relationship like items belonging to shopping carts is more about the model code than it is about the migration code.

Comment: First, thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! I guess I shouldve provided in context this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589399/add-nullable-foreign-key-in-rails/37803756 -----> Which is where I found somebody suggesting (or I misread, which is twice as likely) that optional might be used as a part of migrations.

Comment: Ah, if you're talking about that answer with 14 upvotes, the part that says "in `article` model" is the key there. You'd use optional in Article.rb like `belongs_to :author, optional: true` to indicate that the `author_id` column on an Article record might be `null`.

Comment: Aha. Thanks so much!